# Control de warnings en Python. Modificar el mensaje

Tags: python, python-3.x

En mi proyecto me sale un warning de tipo `InsecureRequestWarning`. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de modificar el mensaje que sale por la terminal por un `print()` personalizado.

Mi idea es que sea algo similar al `try`, `exception`. Donde yo pueda definir, si hay "X" warning muéstrame/haz tal mensaje/acción.

Soy consciente de que puedo quitar los warnings, pero no quiero hacerlo. Quiero ser siempre consciente de él viendo un mensaje de alerta, pero quiero modificar el mensaje que sale, pues es muy largo y molesto.

¿Esto se puede hacer? Siento no poner código, pero es que no encuentro como hacerlo.

¡Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Dado que mencionas el manejo de excepciones, puedes filtrar el warning mediante [`warnings.filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) y elevarlo a categoría de excepción y capturarla con un `try-except`.

Es recomendable que el filtro sea lo más selectivo posible y que se aplique además de forma temporal. Para el ejemplo, voy a asumir (dado el nombre del warning y que no proporcionas detalles de su procedencia) que la excepción proviene de `urllib3` (directamente porque usas esta biblioteca o indirectamente porque usas paquetes que la usan como `requets`):

```
import warnings
import urllib3


with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        'error',
        category=urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning,
        )
    try:
        # Código que puede generar el warning()
    except urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning:
        print("Algo fue muy mal...XD")
```

puedes usar los argumentos `message` y `module` para realizar un filtro más selectivo aún. Ambos esperan realmente un patrón regex, el primero servirá para buscar en e propio mensaje del warning, mientras que `module` sirve para seleccionar solo warnings procedentes de algunos módulos determinados.

Imaginemos que tenemos un módulo llamado `api_core.py` que tiene una función `make_request` que nos puede lanzar el warning:

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.

Podemos filtrar dicho warning mediante:

```
import warnings
import api_core


with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        'error',
        message="Unverified HTTPS request",
        module="api_core",
        category=Warning,
        )

     try:
         api_core.make_request()
     except Warning:
         print("Algo salió muy mal... XD")
```

Otra posibilidad es no elevar e warning a nivel de excepción y asignar una función propia a `warning.showarning` para que haga lo que queramos hacer con el warning:

```
import warnings
import api_core

def showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    print("Algo salió muy mal... XD")

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        'always',
        message="Unverified HTTPS request",
        module="api_core",
        category=Warning,
        )

    warnings.showwarning = showwarning
    api_core.make_request()
```

En el momento que se salga del bloque `try-except` el warning se comportará como lo hacía antes.

> **AVISO**: `warnings.catch_warnings` modifica el estado global del módulo, por lo que no es thread-safe.